# App built in Android Studio runs on Emulator but shows incompatibility on the device

Tags: android, flutter, installation, apk, manifest

I have a problem with an app created in Android Studio. I developed a fairly complex app. The issue is that it runs perfectly on the Android emulator on my PC. There are no warnings or errors, everything is fine.

When I build it, everything also goes perfect, without any alerts (it takes approximately 5 hours).

However, when I try to install the `.apk` on my phone, it throws an error saying:

> the app couldn't be installed because it's incompatible with the device

Even though there are no errors in Android Studio, and during the build process.

The `manifest.xml` is (I have removed the google map key permission)

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.ardigo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:label="ardigo" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<!--  Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.  -->
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
<!--  Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame.  -->
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<!--  Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java  -->
<meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and this is the `gradle.build`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.altoke.altoke"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried different SDK and Gradle versions, but same problem.

Comment: did you try delete old version app ?

Comment: do you mean, on the real smartphone? I have tried on 4 different phones, I and didn't find old versions on my phone, should I check something especial?

Comment: Maybe you can share with me your error output

Comment: I would do it, but, how can I get the  info of an error produced only in a real phone? because in the simulator always works

Comment: Please post the full AndroidManifest.xml of the generated APK, not only the part you wrote in Android Studio.

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml I posted is the one generated from the build.

Comment: `I would do it, but, how can I get the info of an error produced only in a real phone?` You can install a logcat viewer app such as [MatLog](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=MatLog&c=apps&hl=de_CH&gl=US) on your **smartphone** and view, stop, filter, save, etc. the log and hopefully find the error.

Comment: `it takes approximately 5 hours).`

Comment: I built the app (it took 5 hrs), and that is the log, maybe... am I wrong? That cannot be the manifest?

I installed LogCat, as you mentioned, but there is no error msg in the log. when I try to install it, only appears this window message: "the app has not been installed because it is incompatible with the phone" (but in spanish haha). I have tried in 5 different smartphones, and it is always the same.

Comment: I have installed the LogCat, but there is no error or message when I try to install it. The LogCat works well, but the failed installation doesn't show an error message.